# Android RecyclerView Pagination not working if recyclerview does not take full screen height

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview with a bottom tab bar below it I have tried to achieve this using lots of code snippets but the event just wont get called 
This is how i am trying it, first i created a Listener and then used it in my fragment.

```
public abstract class EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
    public static String TAG = EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener.class
            .getSimpleName();

    private int previousTotal = 0;
    private boolean loading = true;
    private int visibleThreshold = 5;
    int firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;

    private int current_page = 1;

    private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;

    public EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(
            LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager) {
        this.mLinearLayoutManager = linearLayoutManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
        totalItemCount = mLinearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
        firstVisibleItem = mLinearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

        if (loading) {
            if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                loading = false;
                previousTotal = totalItemCount;
            }
        }
        if (!loading
                && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
            // End has been reached

            // Do something
            current_page++;

            onLoadMore(current_page);

            loading = true;
        }
    }

    public abstract void onLoadMore(int current_page);
}
```

this is th code i write in my fragment

```
rv_influencer.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener((linearLayoutManager)) {
    @Override
    public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {
        page_no++;
        getInfluencerData();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Scroll", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

});
```

Comment: xml issue for height

Comment: layout height is match_parent for recyclerview

Comment: Any idea why this might not be working ??